# How do i make my batch file have 2 responses.. but have them randomized

Tags: batch-file, chatbot

USER: hello,

AI: hi  or  hello

how would i make the chat bot say one of them but make it randomized?
(i am making a chat bot, but how would i make a random response instead of the same generic one.. )

Comment: You're making a chatbot with a batch file? Really?

Comment: @NathanTuggy - in my experience, chat bots and RPGs make up the vast majority of first projects for people new to batch.

Comment: @SomethingDark: In my day, we made CLI menus and automated sysadmin tasks. CMD can certainly make a valiant attempt at making a decent adventure game or response script, if you pour enough elbow grease in, but it seems so spectacularly unsuited to anything non-trivial it's hard to imagine sticking with it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - it's nice to not have to go onto basically any Windows machine and not worry if the language is installed (like Java, Python, Perl etc.) or if the permissions are set correctly for it to run properly (like PowerShell). I've been doing batch for almost three years now, and at this point it's a combination of "I like the challenge" and "I really don't know anything else except VBA."

Answer (score 2):

%random% returns between 0 and 32767.
So use %random% and change the response depend on the value is odd or even. Like this.

```
set /a NUMCACHE = %random%%%2
IF %NUMCACHE% == 1 (echo hi) else (echo hello)
```